How to parent a objects component to another object, so that only the component moves with the object?
I have two objects in my scene, a line called curve1 and a circle called nurbsCircle1. I want to attach one end of curve1 line to  the nurbsCircle1 shape.
So that when I move the circle, one end of curve1 will always move with the circle, with the other side of curve1 always staying put. Something like this example
I have asked this question in other places but I did not get any answers. The only place that I got an answer from was Reddit but it was entirely in code:
import maya.cmds as mc
c = mc.circle()[0]
l = mc.curve(d=1,p=[(-1,0,0), (0,0,5)], k= (0,1))
cls = mc.cluster(l +'.cv[0]',)[1]
mc.select(c,cls)
mc.pathAnimation()

The code works and I do understand it but I am just switching to Maya and I wanted to understand how to do this with the UI first, then through code. Interestingly enough, the person mentions there are "a hundred ways" to do this.
Could someone share with me one way on how to do this with the UI?

all of those are menu commands with same name.
